# Solution of a nonlinear first order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is it possible to find an analytic solution to the following ODE:
$$y\ln(xy)y'+x=0 $$

It is neither separable nor can be made an exact one. I cannot seem to work any substitution either. I've also tried on Wolfram and returned no solution, that's why I think that the solution is a non elementary function.

Any hints on how to solve this analytically?

Comment: Taking $x=(2^{-1/2}u)^{1/2}$ and $y=(2^{1/2}\xi)^{1/2}$ yields a simpler equation 
\begin{align}
u'_\xi+\log(\xi u)=0.
\end{align}

Comment: Then taking $u=-\tau e^{z/2}/2$ and $\xi=e^{z/2}$, where $z=w+\tau/2-\log(-\tau/2)$ we arrive at an Abel Equation of the second kind,
\begin{align}
ww'_\tau=\left(\frac1\tau-\frac12\right)w+1.
\end{align}
There are solutions for similar equations, the most close being $ww'_\tau=a(1-b/\tau)w+a^2b$ (which yields a parametric solution), but I cannot transform this into an equation with known solutions or find it myself.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps u mean : yln(xy)x'+x=0

$Ln(xy)=z$

$x=\frac{e^{z}}{y}$

$x'=\frac{z'e^{z}}{y}-\frac{e^{z}}{y^{2}}$

$zy(\frac{z'e^{z}}{y}-\frac{e^{z}}{y^{2}})+\frac{e^{z}}{y}=0$

$zz'=(\frac{z-1}{y})$

$\int(\frac {z}{z-1})dz=\int(\frac{1}{y})dy$

$z+\ln(z-1)-\ln(y)=\ln(c)$

$\ln(xy)-\ln(y)+\ln(\ln(xy)-1)=\ln(c)$

$ln(x(\ln(xy)-1))=\ln(c)$

$$x(\ln(xy)-1)=c$$

Comment: I said it! Maybe the meaning of the question is the form that I wrote... otherwise, the original equation of the question does not have an exact answer!!!